# Is there a way to restore a field (in views) which has been removed using 'this block (override)'

Tags: views, entities

I am working with a view that has several sub-views and several fields which are common to all sub-views.  I removes a common field from one of the sub views by selecting it, setting the designation drop-down to 'this block (override)', and clicking the remove button.  This removed the field from the sub view without effecting any of the other sub-views (or the main view.)  I realized the I made a mistake when I removed that field and I would like to restore it.  Is there a way to revert an override on a view field that is no longer available on a sub view?  I would like to avoid re-adding a common filed to a sub-view (which will only be used for that sub view.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically revert the fields on the sub-view back to the master settings and list by:

-- clicking on the down arrow on the top right of the FIELDS section.

-- In the popup, change the **For** dropdown value to **Revert to Default**. This should effectively bring back the master list of fields, assuming that's where your missing field is.

-- any customisation for this specific view's fields must be re-done.

This same process can be done on any of the panes on the view's edit page - `/admin/structure/views/view/my-view` - if you want to revert anything.

Comment: I thought that the 'override' operation was performed on a field-by-field bases.  So your saying that when you select override, every field is overridden (with the default value?)  That would explain some 'strange' behavior that I have seen.

Comment: Well, yes and no. When you create a new display and select an override on ONE field, the whole set of fields is overridden. But when you do the process I stated above and select **Revert to Default**, all the fields revert to default. And this doesn't just apply to the fields section. It applies to all sections with the down arrow.